# WeChat SDK 1.1 iOS6 crash

Tags: uipasteboard

Hi I'm using wechat sdk 1.1 on my application and when I send request to open wechat, it crashes with this error mesage

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPasteboard setValue:forPasteboardType:]: value is not a valid property list type'
```

This only occurs on ios6 though. It is working fine on ios5. My code is something like this:

```
SendMessageToWXReq* req = [[SendMessageToWXReq alloc] init];
req.bText = YES;
req.text = @"testing";

[WXApi sendReq:req];
```

Answer (score 0):

The WeChat devs haven't fixed this problem yet, so it's fair to say WeChat doesn't support iOS6. Or you can mail weixinapp@qq.com for an iOS6 patch.

Note: So far, its new SDK that supports armv7 & arm7s seems to have solved this problem. Add the new SDK into your project, remove reference to the old one, and add reference to this new one.